# Use find, cat, etc... to generate an M3U playlist from album playlists

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have a music folder with selected playlists in each folder titled "playlist.m3u" (should also match *.m3u8).

What I would like to do is have a shell script generate a playlist concatenated with all these selected tracks. But in order for the playlist to work properly, the folder name has to be prepended before the song title.

Here's an example directory structure:

```
Main Folder
 `-> Album 1/
       *.flac
       playlist.m3u
 `-> Album 2/
       *.flac
       playlist.m3u
 `-> Album 3/
       *.mp3
       playlist.m3u
```

The resulting main-playlist.m3u file should look something like this:

```
Album 1/01. Song1.flac
Album 1/02. Song2.flac
Album 1/03. Song3.flac
Album 1/04. Song4.flac
Album 2/1-01. Song1 (Disc 1).flac
Album 2/1-02. Song2 (Disc 1).flac
Album 2/2-01. Song1 (Disc 2).flac
Album 2/2-02. Song2 (Disc 2).flac
Album 3/001. Song 001.mp3
Album 3/002. Song 002.mp3
Album 3/003. Song 002.mp3
<...>
Album 3/100. Song 100.mp3
Album 3/101. Song 101.mp3
```

What is the best and most efficient way for doing this for a song library with, eventually, thousands of tracks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'll just post a way I was able to figure this out.

```
#!/bin/sh

for album in */; do
    while read -r track; do
        printf "%s%s\n" "$album" "$track"
    done < "${album}/playlist.m3u"
done > "main-playlist.m3u"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `find`? e.g.:

```
find . -type f -name '*.flac' -or -name '*.mp3'
```

Or with absolute paths:

```
find $PWD -type f -name '*.flac' -or -name '*.mp3'
```

Case insensitive:

```
find $PWD -type f -iname '*.flac' -or -iname '*.mp3'
```

If you really want to extract the list from these "m3u" files, something like this would work:

```
find . -name '*.m3u' -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' plist; do
  len=$(wc -l < "$plist")
  dir=$(dirname "$plist")
  paste -d/ <(yes "$dir" | head -n$len) "$plist"
done
```